# Diálogo de confirmación desde controlador en CoideIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, model-view-controller

Buenos días,

necesito realizar una pregunta al usuario desde un método del controlador de CodeIgniter. ¿Es posible lanzar la pregunta y, una vez esta vez esta sea respondida, seguir la ejecución del método del controlador... o es necesario cargar una vista para la pregunta y volver a lanzar la llamada al controlador cuando esta sea respondida?

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hay una sección donde explica bien cómo formular la pregunta, así que te pediría por favor que la editases para que quedase de una forma más clara. Aún así te la voy respondiendo abajo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas,

Una vez un controlador emite una respuesta, pierde el hilo de ejecución.

Si quieres realizar preguntas al cliente y que en función de su respuesta el servidor ejecute un código u otro, te recomiendo que utilices en el cliente llamadas Ajax.

Un ejemplo de esto sería (pregunta de confirmación de guardar):

- El controlador emite una vista con información de una factura.
- Pulsamos un botón de guardar en la vista, lo que activa un cuadro de confirmación a través de JavaScript, al pulsarlo llama vía Ajax al controlador (enviará "sí" o "no").
- El controlador recibe el "sí" o el "no", realizando la lógica que desees, y tras eso devolverá una respuesta en JSON, para que el cliente a través de JavaScript tenga retroalimentación (feedback) de la operación.

Te recomiendo que leas un poco sobre llamadas asíncronas para que entiendas mejor el funcionamiento.

EDIT: Edito para comentar que también se puede realizar a través de Sockets, pero entiendo que necesitas lo que te he comentado.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.

Saludos!!

Comment: Hola Hector, muchas gracias por tu amplia y clara respuesta.

Comment: Hola Hector, muchas gracias por tu amplia y clara respuesta. He usado Ajax en varias partes del sistema, el problema de esta pregunta es que sólo debe hacerse cuando se cumplen ciertas circunstancias con la Base de Datos (es una eliminación y se pregunta para confirmar cuando tiene relaciones). Entonces entendí que no se podía, al tener que realizar por tanto dos llamadas AJAX encadenadas (una para conocer si hay que realizar la pregunta y otra en función de cual es la respuesta)... voy a darle alguna vuelta más, intento implementarlo y comento si ha funcionado. Muchas gracias de nuevo! ;D

Comment: @OscarAlonso Buenas de nuevo. Puedes realizar la llamada AJAX para ver si tiene relaciones, entonces devuelves un JSON que active la pregunta en JavaScript, que llevaría ya finalmente mediante AJAX a la parte de la eliminación o desees realizar. (Si la respuesta contesta a tu pregunta márcala como válida). Saludos!!

Comment: Perfecto, intento implementar lo que comentas y comento el resultado, por si puede servir a alguien en el futuro. Creo que ya he marcado la pregunta como válida. Un saludo y gracias!! ;D